# How to disable push notification in Firefox wth Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I found two examples on Stack Overflow on disabling notifications, but neither of these has worked for me: push notifications are still showing when the browser is launched. Here is the code that I've tried:

Example 1:

```
browser_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser_profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=browser_profile)
```

Example 2:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()
options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```

Notification

[image]

Comment: Can you update the question with the _snapshot_ of the notification which you want to _disable_?

Comment: @DebanjanB updated question with a screenshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found solution from official Firefox website https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox

```
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options)
```